# What does version attribute mean in .xsl declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new in xslt and some fundamental questions bother me. One of them is:

What `version="1.0"` mean in my stylesheet, when I am using xslt 2.0 processor. Even if I have (in my stylesheet) non 1.0 function, it is processed despite I have explicitly declared the stylesheet version to 1.0.

To me, it seems that `version` attribute has no property beyond informative.
It doesn't configure the processor. Then it serves for what?

The other question is:

Is there any relation between the versions of (xslt processor), (xslt stylesheet) and (xpath)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Martin's answer is correct, but I would also add that it MAY configure the processor: some IDEs decide which XSLT processor to invoke based on what they find in the version attribute.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards, if the XSLT 2.0 processor supports it then `version="1.0"` enables backwards compatible processing, one major difference then is that `<xsl:value-of select="foo"/>` outputs a text node with the string value of the first selected `foo` element while `version="2.0"` would output the values of all selected `foo` elements.

As an example see http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh2R, it processes the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <item>foo</item>
        <item>bar</item>
    </items>
</root>
```

with the stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <result version="2.0">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </result>
            <result version="1.0">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="backwards"/>
            </result>       
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items" version="1.0" mode="backwards">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

where there are two `template match="items"` in different modes and one template uses `version="1.0"`, the result of the stylesheet is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <result version="2.0">
      <root>
         <items>foo bar</items>
      </root>
   </result>
   <result version="1.0">
      <root>
         <items>foo</items>
      </root>
   </result>
</result>
```

which demonstrates the difference of the `value-of select="item"` evaluation depending on the `version`.